# What FPGA Devboard to start learning

Tags: microcontroller

so I want to get into FPGA mainly because I am interested in emulating retro hardware, and improving my understanding of ic logic, and the idea of being able to create my own chips(well sort of :)) just sounds super awesome.

So the question is what do you need to start ?
Generally I don't have a lot of money so I'd like to stick with the 100 € models.
Here are some things I am unsure of.
Lots of the very cheap boards disclaim that there is no programmer/ debugger included, what is important to me is that I can program the chip without having to get a lot of extra hardware, so a mostly all in one package would be good. If thats not feasible some info on the minimum set up required to get started would be appreciated.

I have all sorts of electronics stuff already, Arduinos and Raspbis, breadboards the like so some basic equipment already exists.
So any suggestions ?
thanks for the input and cheers,
Passifi

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I have used `Altera Cyclone® II 90nm FPGA development board` and `EDGE Spartan FPGA` ,  in my university.  Altera cycle 2 is a great development board with onboard switches, 7segment displays and LCD, but quite expensive. However, if you are looking for something cheap, then maybe check out  `ALTERA FPGA Cyclone II EP2C5T144 System Development Board` and `EDGE Spartan 6 FPGA Development Board.`